# Unable to call static method of data manager class in the code behind page of main aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, static-methods

I am trying to do simple data entry. I have my aspx file for input and data manager file in App_Code folder to interact with data entity. I have "static" add method but I cant add the model file with "using dataModel" line and cant call the static method in code behind...

What am I missing?

main.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using dataModel;     // <------------- cant add this one..gives error

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataManager em = new dataManager();
        em.add(...)
    }
}
```

dataManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class dataManager
{

    // Add a new customer
    public static void add(...)
    {
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks AVD and Phil... Much appreciated... I will remember the concept of static method from this point onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are not called on instances. The following will work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataManager.add(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Methof `add` is static method so try this:

```
dataManager.add(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataManager.Add(..);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a closer look at

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You do not need to instanciate the dataManger to be able to call the static method.

You can call the method striaht like this

```
dataManager.add(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no namespace named dataModel, so the using statement doesn't make sense.  Your dataManager class ins in the global namespace in the code you posted.

As others mentioned, there's no need to create an instance of dataManager to call the static method.